# style.css file location in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a style.css file which is common across all the apps in my Django project. It is located as follows:

```
testsite______
              |
              |
           testsite
              |
              |
             news 
              |
              |
            reviews
              |
              |
           templates------>static------>css------> style.css
              |
              |
           manage.py
```

In settings.py of the project, I have `STATICFILES_DIRS` as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        "/path/to/my/project/templates/static/",
)
```

I call the css files in the header of my template as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEst site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css"/>
    </head>
```

However, the css doesn't load. It gives a 404 error wherein the server looks for the css file inside the app (news, reviews). The error is as follows:

```
"GET /test-site/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4147
```

Do I need to specify something for css in the urls.py? What am I missing out here?

Comment: do you have `django.contrib.staticfile` in `INSTALLED_APPS `? [more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#basic-usage)

Comment: @karthikr - yes, `django.contrib.staticfile` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you dont have to specify anything of the css in the urls.
Try to put into the HTML

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

and to call a

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
```

I do it like that and it works fine.